# I'm having trouble initializing a 1604A-V1.2 Character module

Tags: lcd

I have a product that uses a 4 line x 16 character LCD display module. It works fine with the original 1604 model, but the display has evidently been updated with an SPLC780C control chip. It will not initialize. From the datasheet, it appears to emulate the HD44780 just like the original, But it will not initialize. I get the normal block characters on line one and line 3 that you get if just powering it up.

Does anyone here know what the problem might be?
Here is the init code:

```
\\\
void lcd_init(void) 
{
   unsigned int8 i;
   unsigned int8 LCD_INIT_STRING[4] = {0x20 | (LCD_TYPE << 2), 0x0C, 1, 6};
                              //{0x22, 0x4, 1, 6}
                             // These bytes need to be sent to the LCD
                             // to start it up.
   

   lcd_output_enable(0);
   lcd_output_rs(0);
   lcd_output_rw(0);

 #if defined(__PCB__)
   set_tris_lcd(LCD_OUTPUT_MAP);
 #else
  #if (defined(LCD_DATA4) && defined(LCD_DATA5) && defined(LCD_DATA6) && 
  defined(LCD_DATA7))
   output_drive(LCD_DATA4);
   output_drive(LCD_DATA5);
   output_drive(LCD_DATA6);
   output_drive(LCD_DATA7);
  #else
   lcdtris.data = 0x0;
  #endif
   lcd_enable_tris();
   lcd_rs_tris();
   lcd_rw_tris();
 #endif
    
   delay_ms(450);

for(i=1;i<=3;++i)
   {
       lcd_send_nibble(3);
       delay_ms(45);
   }
   
   
   delay_ms(15);
   for(i=0;i<=4;++i)
     {
      lcd_send_byte(0,LCD_INIT_STRING[i]);
      delay_ms(45);
     }
   lcd_send_nibble(8);
   lcd_send_nibble(0);
   lcd_send_nibble(8);
   lcd_send_nibble(0);
   lcd_send_nibble(1);
   lcd_send_nibble(0);
   lcd_send_nibble(4);
   

  #if defined(LCD_EXTENDED_NEWLINE)
   g_LcdX = 0;
   g_LcdY = 0;
  #endif
}
\\\
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here for me, but I found an iconoclast solution for
the bad lines. A negative `setcursor` like that:

```
lcd.setCursor(-4,2);
lcd.setCursor(-4,3);
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. :-( I still can't seem to initialize this thing. I've slowed the timing down to ridiculous, I mean I can watch the older display I have print like I'm on a 300 baud modem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i was too fast for answer but i want precise that i had
a problem with a new LCD1604-16char,thinking i bought a 2004 one!!
but two lines couldn't get from the beginning,so i've made a negative
setcursor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).